# Return deleted project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, data-recovery

I have serious problem, I have deleted Java project from Eclipse and I don't have fresh revision on CVS. Is there any chance anyway  to return that project or I am najebao  ?

Comment: Have you deleted it from the disk also ?

Comment: If it was deleted from disk this would be a better question suited for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Yes, folder is empty. And what is the best I don't remember how I done that ( I needed to check button to click ok )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Eclipse - Managing Files and Projects](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/winter2005/cmsc298P/EclipseTutorial/advanced.html) says:

> To delete a project right click on the
>   project in the package viewer.  Again,
>   select "Delete" from the context menu.
>   This time, a dialog box will appear
>   asking you if you want to also delete
>   all of the files in the project's
>   directory. The default is "Do not
>   delete contents". If you select this
>   option, the Java files that were a
>   part of that project will not be
>   deleted.  If you are sure you no
>   longer need the project delete the
>   contents instead.

So may be you just deleted it from eclipse but it is still on your hardisk. Otherwise you have to use [Data Recovery Softwares](http://lifehacker.com/5237503/five-best-free-data-recovery-tools)

Comment: Just a note, both links are outdated. The first has restricted access and the second is a 404.

Answer (score 0):

If you only happened to delete the project in eclipse, but left the "Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)" unchecked, you can restore the project. This is done by using File/Import, selecting "Existing Projects into Workspace" and browsing towards the location on your hard drive, where you had preciously stored your project.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting a project from disk, there is no way Eclipse can restore it. However, depending on your operating system, it might still be in your Trash folder. If it's not, then this is indeed a question of data recovery.