# Eclipse Undo after Project Delete operation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an RCP application similar to eclipse.

For eclipse in project navigator, if we delete a project (also the checkbox is marked for deleting the project content from the disk) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, we can see the project is back again but with no content and in most of the case the nature of the project is also gone. I am not able to understand this phenomena. Why a project delete operation should be undoable when the content from the disk is also being deleted?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the project **with** the checkbox "Delete project contents on disk" your data is gone. You can not undo this operation.

If you do not select the checkbox Eclipse will be able to 'recover' all of your project.

[image]

Related questions:

- [Return deleted project from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556438/return-deleted-project-from-eclipse)
- [Eclipse project was deleted how to undo it? or recover it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736733/eclipse-project-was-deleted-how-to-undo-it-or-recover-it)

Comment: Project delete operation is still undo-able even after marking option "Delete project contents on disk". It just brings the project back not the content in it.

Answer (score 0):

try eclipse local history. You might able to recover some source files. Your best bet

Comment: Project delete operation is still undo-able even after marking option "Delete project contents on disk". It just brings the project back not the content in it.